# How do I convert from wav to GSM under Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, codecs, convert

I would like to convert some wav files to GSM:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM

How can I go about this under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to do under a standard installation of Ubuntu but not completely impossible. *Possibilities* are:

1. The best way is to use a suitable compiled FFmpeg with the following commmand line:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i test.wav -c:a libgsm -ar 8000 -ab 13000 -ac 1 -f gsm test.gsm
   ```

   But Xenial's FFmpeg is not compiled with `libgsm` unfortunately so this cannot be easily accomplished without recompiling.
2. Another more workable option is to use `sox`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
   ```

   and then use the following command line:

   ```
   sox test.wav -r 8000 -c 1 test.gsm
   ```

   This works well under Xenial Xerus.
3. A third option is to use the `libgsm-tools` package by running the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgsm-tools
   ```

   and then using this command line:

   ```
   toast -p test.wav
   ```

   but this produces an unplayable file under Xenial so not a good option...
4. And for those who like to use a gui `audacity` can produce playable gsm files but this is not possible under Xenial's package unfortunately...

Not a happy situation for Ubuntu with the only *reasonable* option being to use example no. 2 with `sox`...

Comment: `sox` is also a good option for any Debian distro in general.

Comment: It's worth noting that sox determines the output format based on file extension.  It can also create a wav container with the "Microsoft GSM" codec: `sox test.wav -e gsm test_gsm.wav`